# open a new window on click and without page being postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, mouseevent

i have a page that has a grid with rows of data and it has url hidden in each row n when a row is clicked it opens new tabed window and the parent page still stays open with the grid data. i want to have a button that does the same . my aspx is

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="igClientScript">

 function NavigateOnClick(sender, eventArgs) {
     try {
         var row = eventArgs.get_item().get_row().get_index();
         var url = sender.get_rows().get_row(row).get_cell(0).get_text();

         window.open(url);
     }
     catch (e) {

     }
 }   
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Entity"></asp:Label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">

   <asp:ListItem>Select Entity</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="EntityName"></asp:Label>
     <asp:Button ID="newEntity" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="newEntity_Click" OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"  />
<ig:WebScriptManager ID="WebScriptManager1" runat="server"></ig:WebScriptManager>
<ig:WebDataGrid ID="EntityGrid" runat="server"  Width="100%" Height="50%" StyleSetName="Claymation" >
          <Columns>

          </Columns>
    <ClientEvents Click="NavigateOnClick" />

</ig:WebDataGrid>   

</div>
```

I want something like window.open =(entity,_newtab) without doing a page post back how can i get this?

Comment: did you tried any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what worked part of my problem was that the url is dynamic i created a label that is updated on dropdown selection and pass the label text while creating the url instead of asp button went with html button  function opentab(sender, eventArgs) {
          try {
              var name = document.getElementById('EntityName');
              var url = name.textContent;
              window.open(url+"Edit.aspx");
          }catch(e){
          }
      }which wont cause a postback

Answer (score 0):

Just use

`window.open(url, 'random_name');`

Refer this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Thank you Kailash Yadav this opens new window not a tabbed window and the parent if refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute to your button:

```
target="_blank"

button.attributes.add("target","_blank");
```

Comment: thank you  user2146515 this open in same window . i want the parent to stay as is and open new tab

Comment: http://www.charith.gunasekara.web-sphere.co.uk/2010/05/opening-new-window-after-executing-some.html Check this out, This might help